# adding column in view not present in database table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database. Let's say that it has 3 fields: `field1,field2,field3`. Now I want to create a view which will contain field1,field2, and filed4, where filed4 is the new filed. Now I want to know Is it possible to make such a view. if yes then how?

I am using MySQL query browser version 1.1.20

Comment: Is field4 going to be calculated from the other fields? What's your current code for the view?

Comment: What content do you want field4 to have?

Comment: Yes, perfectly possible. Next.

Comment: No field4 is not going to be calculated from other fields. It is actually a status field which is **totally new** and was **not defined in the database table**.

my current code for view is :- 
create view myview as select field1,field2, **field4** from table_name;

Comment: could you please kindly tell me how to write that?? @Strawberry

Comment: `CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT field1, 'hello world' field4 FROM my_table;`

Comment: thanks a lot @Strawberry